# Medalha "Esportista" deveria ser "Espírito Esportivo"?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

A medalha **Esportista** é equivalente ao badge **Sportsmanship** do Stack Overflow original. A melhor tradução para este termo, e que melhor passa a ideia por trás da medalha, não seria **Espírito Esportivo**?

Comment: Sim! Eu estava para sugerir exatamente essa tradução.

Comment: @bfavaretto O que me deixa intrigado é que a comunidade se ofereceu pra ajudar a traduzir, mas me parece que foi contratado um serviço para isso (corrija me se for o caso). Queria entender essa baixa qualidade generalizada de tradução paga para pt-BR, pois não acontece só com o SO.

Comment: @Bacco Fiquei tão perplexo quanto você, tendo sido um dos que se ofereceram para traduzir. Não entendi essa decisão da SE, como já [disse antes](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87). Quanto à má qualidade das traduções em geral, acho que é por falta de conhecimento das ferramentas que estão sendo traduzidas, aliada ao formato de tradução "picada", onde há muitos strings curtos soltos, fora de contexto. E talvez um bocado de falta de competência. Lembra daquela mensagem do Windows Explorer que dizia "verifique a *orografia*"?

Comment: @bfavaretto essa da orografia eu adorava, forçava caminho errado de rede pra mostrar pros outros. Outra boa, do Word, era a ferramenta "elipse" de desenho, que foi traduzida para "reticências" (ellipse x ellipsis). Detalhe da "orografia", ela permaneneceu intacta por várias versões seguidas do win. Acho que só num dos SPs do XP ou no 7 ela "foi embora".

Comment: Nem sabia que esportista e esporte faziam parte do dicionário de língua portuguesa. Aqui é **desportista**, PT_pt.